# Find depth of folder given the path in Powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I need to find how deep does the folder go at a given path.
The issue is that the script refuses to work at all.
It prints nothing not a single line.

```
$nmlfpEngD = "\\nml-fp\EngDesignLib\"
$nmlfPrdD = "\\nml-fp\PrdDesignLib\"
$csvFilePath = "\\nml-fp\Users\Scripts\Scripts\Aras\CSVOutput\GetSubFolders.csv"
$subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $nmlfpEngD*  -Directory -Recurse -Force
foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
    $resultObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        StringCount   = $subfolder.FullName.ToString().Split('\').Count
        SubfolderName = $subfolder.Name
        Path          = $subfolder.FullName
        #Exists = 1
    }
    $resultObject | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Append
    Write-Host $resultObject
}
```

When `Recurse` is removed it gets the folder names at depth level 1. But this defeats the purpose.
Is this not the correct use of `Recurse`?

Comment: if you run `Get-ChildItem -Path $nmlfpEngD*  -Directory -Recurse -Force` without assigning to a variable do you get any output?

Comment: I second @SantiagoSquarzon 's suggestion: testing the code on my device has it working as-is (and your use of `-Recurse` is absolutely correct by the way). I suspect it might be a matter of permissions on the subdirectories.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I do get an output when I run just that line in the terminal

Comment: If you get output from the command then there is no explanation as to why you don't get it in the Csv

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like using `LiteralPath` rather than `Path` on UNC paths, but that does not explain why your code fails to write to the file.
When using the `-Recurse` switch, there is no need to end the path with `\*`.

Also, I would use `Select-Object` here instead of a foreach loop and have it create the objects to collect in a variable using [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties).
Then write the whole thing out in one go to the CSV file.

Please try

```
$nmlfpEngD   = '\\nml-fp\EngDesignLib'
$nmlfPrdD    = '\\nml-fp\PrdDesignLib'
$csvFilePath = '\\nml-fp\Users\Scripts\Scripts\Aras\CSVOutput\GetSubFolders.csv'
$dirsep      = [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar

# you can give both paths to Get-ChildItem as array by simply adding a comma in between
$result = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $nmlfpEngD, $nmlfPrdD -Directory -Recurse | 
          # because these are UNC paths, we need to trim off the first two backslashes
          Select-Object @{Name = 'StringCount'; Expression = {$_.FullName.Trim($dirsep).Split($dirsep).Count}}, 
                        @{Name = 'SubfolderName'; Expression = {$_.Name}}, 
                        @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = {$_.FullName}}
# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to Csv
$result | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```